# Bootstrap datepicker trigger change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have from and to input fields with bootstrap date picker. When query params not empty I would like to change the value of these input fields and trigger the change date event on datepicker because I have a function that calculates total price between dates. When user selects dates from datepicker works fine but if I change the value by jquery it does not calculate.

```
$('#from').val('<%= @from_date %>').trigger( 'change' );
$('#to').val('<%= @to_date %>').trigger( 'change' );
//function
var dates_avail = new DatesAvailability({
                start: '#from',
                end: '#to'
});

..
W.DatesAvailability = function (opts) {
var options = $.extend({}, defaultOpts, opts);
        var start = options.start + ',' + options.rel_start;
        var end = options.end + ',' + options.rel_end;
        $(start + ',' + end).datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            startDate: '+1d',
            endDate: '+3y',
..
}).
on('changeDate', function (e) {
// I would like to trigger this.
..
```

I also have these lines in bootstrap-datepicker.js

```
..
if (fromArgs){
                // setting date by clicking
                this.setValue();
                this.element.change();
            }
            else if (this.dates.length){
                // setting date by typing
                if (String(oldDates) !== String(this.dates) && fromArgs) {
                    this._trigger('changeDate');
                    this.element.change();
                }
            }
..
```

Comment: how are you changing the value by jQuery? Did you try any of `setDate`,  and `setUTCDate`?

Comment: I am changing the value of the input field, with the bootstrap datepicker's date format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the update mention in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update). Something like `$(start + ',' + end).datepicker('update', qParamStart);

If you're trying to figure out how to get the query params [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) is a good reference.

Comment: Thank you update function updates the field. But does not fire on(changeDate) function of bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by manually calling the event `changeDate`.

E.g.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().trigger('changeDate');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('_trigger', 'changeDate');
```

This uses an undocumented private method, but will fire with event and the extra data you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the link from the calendar then call it conventionally. For me it was:

```
$('.ui-state-active').click();
```

or

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();
```